# adding data to only few column of an empty dataframe in pandas for each iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code in which there is a loop and the output of each iteration is creating a dataframe `df1` with different column names, say in iteration 1, the dataframe `df1` created is giving me column A, B, C and in iteration 2 the columns are A, X, D. There is only a single record as the output for each dataframe.

In total there can be 26 distinct column and one iteration_seq column. I created a pandas empty dataframe `df2` with all the possible columns.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['iteration_seq','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 
                          'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
                          'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])



lis = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 
   'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

import random
random.shuffle(lis)
import numpy as np

for i in range(len(lis)-1):
    pax = lis[i]   # we have problem from here, say I want to take any aribitrary variable and put random value in that, and then update the df2, and later append the df2 in the df1 
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['iteration_seq'])
    df2[pax] = np.random.rand(1,1000)) # and how to take a variable value as column value, in R we had the option of "with"
    df2['iteration_seq'] = i+1
```

How can I put the values of each iteration of the loop, as a separate row in the empty dataframe df2 for only the column which are in the output of the loop in df1, along with an additional column specifying the iteration number.

Comment: Why are you not showing any of the code but instead just describing it? Please give an [mcve]

Comment: I have added some code for demonstration.